# Redirecting aspx files to html on a windows server

Tags: asp.net, html, windows, .htaccess

I am in the process of migrating an ASP.net to an HTML website. This is new to me as I only usually do designs for websites.

The URL is the same and so are all the file names (apart from the extensions, of course). I have no clue on ASP.net websites which is where I am getting stuck. I am running the site on a Windows Server and would like to be able to re-direct all the `.aspx` files to the corresponding `.html` files

I have read up about `.htaccess` but have had no luck, I think I need to be running Apache?

Does anybody have any idea how I can solve this? There are similar questions on here but the answers aren't dumbed down enough for me!

Also, when i try the `htaccess` option I get this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.  Requested URL: /about-us.aspx

Comment: Correct solution: use IIS rewrite rules. Easy solution: serve .aspx files as HTML and keep the old extension. Even easier solution: switch to apache.

Comment: I have no idea about asp.net and i do not own the original files. The only resources I have are the file names and the content. I have no clue about asp.net so that option would take me forever. Could you go into more detail about IIS rewrite rules? Thanks

Comment: I didn't say anything about writing ASPX. Just rename your HTML to ASPX and configure IIS to serve them as HTML.

Comment: Ah I see, I am hosting on godaddy and I don't think I have full access to the IIS

Comment: Before you get started on renaming files, you should know that if you do (rename) and they actually provided some functionality (you didn't specify) - even if its not immediately apparent to you, then all that functionality stops dead in its tracks. Provide (or obtain) more info before you start doing anything.

Comment: Every page just displays text and images. I have very little knowledge of server side stuff etc so i apologise for my lack of information. The client demands that all pages should end in .html and is hosted on a windows server. I do not own the asp.net website/application i just have the file names.

Comment: @LewisMorgan that doesn't really mean anything - almost all web sites, including SO is just "text and images" - but there's a lot going on under the covers. If you don't have enough expertise, can't determine, then it's time to ask those who do - there is no point in making a decision you can't make (really). Post some screenshots of the directory structures (at least) if you want SO folk to try - particularly the **/bin** folder.

Answer (score 0):

**KISS solution:**  If there are only a few number of pages and there really is no logic in the .aspx pages, you could always just load all of the possible web pages, and save them as .html pages via the browser functionality.  Google Chrome allows you to right-click on each page and choose **Save as...**  Internet Explorer & Firefox have similar functionality.  These pages that you save can then be uploaded to your Go-Daddy site.